# How to count items to reassure that they are present in table SQL

Tags: sql, count

I have DR with Engagements and Funds. So 1 Engagement can have a lot of funds and fund has unique identifier so it can be uploaded in DB only once for 1 Engagement.
Here is the task: I need to find all Engagement which have at least 1 or more funds.
Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this:

```
select * from Engagements 
where exists(select * from Funds where EngagementID = Engagements.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will only return engagements which have funds.

```
   SELECT *
    FROM Engagements
    INNER JOIN Funds ON Engagements.UniqueID = Funds.UniqueID
```

Comment: And if there are no UniqueID columns join with?

Comment: The OP stated there was one, but without a unique ID it does make it difficult

Comment: With a UniqueID in the Funds table JOIN will do fine. If no UniqueID, then the EXISTS alternative is better.